# Swift - func viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, viewwillappear

I have a standard `SingleViewApplication` project.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        println("viewDidLoad");
    }
}
```

When I start the application, viewDidLoad is called.

My scenario:
  - press Home button (`applicationDidEnterBackground`)
  - recall application (`applicationWillEnterForeground`)
and `viewDidLoad` is not called.

Is there another func to override?

Answer (score 58):

If you want to call `viewWillAppear` in swift use this.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon
}
```

Comment: I am curious: can you explain why we need to pass `false`?

Comment: Don't pass false. Pass on the value of "animated" to the super class.

Comment: old habits die hard (';')  :)

Answer (score 8):

The best practice is to register for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterBackgroundNotification` in your ViewController

```
public override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationWillEnterForeground:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationWillEnterBackground:", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("did enter foreground")
}

func applicationWillEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("did enter background")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on Noah response:
on ViewController.swift add refresh function and call it from AppDelegate.swift > applicationWillEnterForeground

```
ViewController.swift  

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        println("viewDidLoad");
        refresh();
    }

    func refresh(){
        println("refresh");
    }
}
```

.

```
AppDelegate.swift
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication!) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    ViewController().refresh();
}
```

Output:

```
viewDidLoad  
refresh  
refresh  
refresh  
refresh
```

Comment: Note that `ViewController().refresh()` creates a new instance of Viewcontroller. Also, since this is not stored anywhere `ARC` will deallocate it quite immediately.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is only called when your view controller’s view is first loaded—it remains in memory after that, so in general it will never be called again until you create another instance of the view controller. If you need to refresh content in your view controller when the application enters the foreground, you should create a method to do that and call it from `applicationWillEnterForeground`.

Answer (score 2):

Same as @Sunkas but in Swift 4:

```
open override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground(notification:)), name: .UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc private func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("will enter foreground")
}

@objc private func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("did enter background")
}
```

Comment: Not sure in which version it got changed but I had to change `name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` to `name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using page view controllers and swiping between the controllers or if you are coming back from background, your `viewDidLoad` does not get called which means your `viewDidLoad` will get called only once. You need to set the data setup in `viewWillAppear()` since it gets called every time the view appears.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` does not get called for me on iOS 15 simulator when an app gets in background, then back into foreground